# How does Java ServiceLoader work during development time? (Unit test before building JARs?)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, serviceloader

Java's ServiceLoader needs those entries to be present inside the JAR file. Is there a way to programatically add those service entries at runtime time for unit testing, when inside the IDE? Especially when the JARs are not built yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't get too hung up focusing on JAR files. They are the preferred way to encapsulate services, but they aren't required. The key is really [`ClassLoader.getResources(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29) - where the `String` arg effectively becomes `("META-INF/services/" + serviceClass.getName())`. One other bit of information to keep in mind is that [`ServiceLoader.load(Class)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load%28java.lang.Class%29) makes use of the [context class loader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader%28%29) (of course, you can also make use of [`ServiceLoader.load(Class, ClassLoader)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)). So...what you really need to do is manipulate the classpath or configure the context class loader in such a way as to make `ServiceLoader` happy.

Comment: Do you know how to do this when project is multi-module?  I have a question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/34619176/1735836